# Counting occurences of integers in a java array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to count occurrences of integers in an array. I would like to be able to modify the following loop that counts characters...

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
     counts[chars[i] - 'a']++;
```

I tried modifying it like this but getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error...

```
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++)
     counts[ints[i] - '0']++;
```

Any ideas?

I have searched through many questions with similar titles but not in the fashion I need.

UPDATED

Here is my updated code. The user enters integers numbered 1 through 25. The program is supposed to count the occurrences of those integers using another array. I updated the code using...

```
counts[vals[i] - 1]++;
```

Which allows the program to compile. However, all the values of count are zeros.

UPDATED CODE...

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class CountIntOccurs
{
   private static final int MAX_NUM_OF_VALUES = 200;

   public static void main ( String [] args )
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
      int[] vals = new int[MAX_NUM_OF_VALUES];
      int numOfVals = 0;

      // Read and store values
      System.out.println( "Enter integers <= 25, one per line, hit control-Z when done: " );
      while ( in.hasNextLine() )
      {
         vals[numOfVals] = Integer.parseInt( in.nextLine() );
         ++numOfVals;
      }

      // Close application if no values entered
      if ( numOfVals == 0 )
         System.exit( 0 );


      //  declare counts array   
      int[] counts = new int[25];


      System.out.println( counts.length );

      //??????? For each integer in the array, count it
      for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++){
         counts[vals[i] - 1]++; 
      }



      //display values enetered
      for ( int i = 0; i < numOfVals; ++i )
      {
            System.out.println( vals[i] );
      }


      //?????? display counted integers????
      for ( int i = 0; i < counts.length; ++i )
      {
            System.out.println( counts[i] );
      }


   }
}
```

Right now , what i need is to display the occurrences of the integers that are input. If I type in 1 1 2 2 2 the results should be 2 3 0 0 0 ... 0 .

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `ints[i]`? Does it really contain the characters `'0'` to `'9'`, or the ints `0` to `9`? My guess is the latter, and it is different.

Comment: ints contains random integer values 1 through 25

Comment: Yes, so integers. And the code is subtracting `'0'`, which is not an integer, it's a character.

Comment: Why is `counts` initialized to `numOfVals`? What if the user inputs 1 value and it's greater than 1?

Comment: Should it not be `counts = new int[25];` if your range is 1 through 25? (If it's 0 through 25, then do `new int[26]`.)

Comment: Ctrl-Z indicates end of file input. However. Im not to the point of addressing that yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
    counts[vals[i]-1]++; 
}
```

This is the problem, because you have `counts.length` instead of `numOfVals`. The loop is supposed to increase the count of some number by 1 for *each entered value*, so you have to keep looping until you have counted every entered value.

If you use `counts.length`, you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `numOfVals` is smaller than `25` (because `counts.length` is initialized to `25`). If `numOfVals` is bigger than `25`, you will only count the first 25 inputs.

The solution is therefore:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfVals; i++) {
    counts[vals[i]-1]++; 
}
```

Now, you are printing every number on a new line by using `println()` instead of `print()`, and you aren't printing any text, so it is hard to interpret the output of the program. I made some superficial changes to the program to make it easier to understand. Here's the complete program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] vals = new int[MAX_NUM_OF_VALUES];
    int numOfVals = 0;

    System.out.println( "Enter integers <= 25, one per line, hit control-Z when done: " );
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        vals[numOfVals] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        ++numOfVals;
    }
    if(numOfVals == 0)
        System.exit(0);

    int[] counts = new int[25];

    //changed counts.length to numOfVals
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfVals; i++) {
        counts[vals[i]-1]++; 
    }

    //display values entered
    System.out.print("Entered values: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfVals; ++i) {
        System.out.print(vals[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(); //new line

    //display counted integers
    System.out.print("Counts of the values: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; ++i) {
        System.out.print(counts[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that if the user enters more than 200 values, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as well, because `MAX_NUM_OF_VALUES` is 200, but you have no way of actually enforcing that.

Answer (score 2):

The point of `- 'a'` is to subtract the ASCII value of `'a'` (97) so that `'a'` falls into index 0 and `'z'` falls into index 25, the assumption being that `chars` only contains lowercase alphabetical characters.

Your code would work if `ints` was a `char` array containing numerical *characters*, that is, values between `'0'` and `'9'`. More likely, it's actually an `int` array, and by subtracting `'0'` (ASCII 48) you end up with a negative index.

To fix the problem, just remove the char subtraction:

```
counts[ints[i]]++;
```

Comment: Reading from their comment, I think they'd probably need `counts[ints[i] - 1]++;`.

Comment: @Tunaki That would be more space-efficient, but less intuitive. Either way could work though.

Comment: Tunaki... I used your suggestion, and the program compiles, yet all the counts values are 0 ... zero

Comment: @codeRed Provide a [mcve] in that case. Our ability to help you is limited like this.

Answer (score -4):

Trying to guess... You need to count the ocorrences of eacth integer?
Like this?

```
   int[] counts = new int[25];
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
        if (ints[i] >= 1 &&  ints[i] <= 25)
            counts[ints[i]-1]++;

   for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
     if (counts[i] > 0)
       System.out.println("number " + String.valueOf(i) + " counts " + String.valueOf(counts[i]));
```

Comment: There are integers larger than 8 (or 9 as you probably intended with `new int[9]`). I think you have totally misunderstood the question.

Comment: The code is counting chars... What do you expected.

Comment: No. It is not counting chars. As you said yourself: *"Only integer... humm ok."* The thing is that he is getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because he's subtracting 97 from the index value (because he is treating the ints like chars), but the value of `ints[i]` ranges from 0 to 24 (or something similar), not 97 to 123, so he's getting a negative index value in `counts[]`.

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer.